# Ignoring folder in .gitignore, what's the different when we put `/` and not putting it?

Tags: git

In .gitignore, we can ignore a folder using as below

```
Folder
/Folder
Folder/
```

Is there any difference between the 3 approaches above? i.e.

1. not putting any `/`
2. putting `/` in front
3. putting `/` behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Folder` ignores a file or directory anywhere in the tree.

`/Folder` ignores a file or directory at the root of the tree.

`Folder/` ignores a directory anywhere in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

[John Zwink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781268/1256452) covers the *question you asked*, but not ones you *didn't* ask, such as: What about `/Folder/`?

To cover *all* cases, we must make a few preliminary notes:

- You can put a `.gitignore` into your working tree at the *top* level, or at any *sub*-level.  That is, you can have:

  ```
  .gitignore
  dir1/.gitignore
  dir1/dir2/.gitignore
  dir1/dir2/file2
  dir1/file1
  file3
  ```

  for instance.
- You can put paths into any of these `.gitignore` files.  For instance, the top level `.gitignore` can list `dir1/dir2/file2`.
- *Any* `.gitignore` can have a *negated entry*, that starts with `!`; the top level `.gitignore` could list `!dir1/dir2/file2` instead.

Next, we must note that an entry in a `.gitignore` can *begin with* a slash, *contain* a slash, and/or *end with* a slash.  That is, any of those `.gitignore` entries could list any or all of the following:

- `/f`
- `/f/`
- `f`
- `f/`
- `/d/f`
- `/d/f/`
- `d/f`
- `d/f/`

plus *all of the same but with `!` at the front*.

This makes **sixteen** (16) possible combinations: prefix-slash, embedded-slash, and trailing-slash, with or without prefix-`!`.  Fortunately for us, there are only eight (8) actual behaviors, resulting from three (3) combinations that we can mix and match any way we like:

- Git can treat the entry you put in as a *folder* (directory) name *only*, or as a folder-*or*-file name.
- Git can treat the entry as *anchored* or *unanchored*.
- Git can treat the entry as *negated* ("don't ignore") or regular ("do ignore").

To mark an entry as *folder/directory only*, the rule is: *add a trailing slash `/`*.

To mark an entry as *anchored*, the rule is: *add a leading `/`, or include an embedded `/` that isn't at the end*.  (The one at the end is already in use, as the "directory/folder mark".)

To mark an entry as *negated*, the rule is: *add a leading `!`* (before any leading `/`).

Hence, for example, `!d/f` matches any directory *or* file named `d/f`, but is "anchored", and in the end, is *negated* as well.  So we *won't* ignore `d/f`.

I borrow the term *anchored* from regular expressions.  It means: *only match at this level*.  That is, given a working tree that contains `dir1/dir2/file2`, if we tell Git to ignore `file2`, it will ignore this `file2` even though it's deep in `dir1/dir2`.  But if we tell Git to ignore `/file2`, it will only ignore a `file2` that's at the same level as the `.gitignore` itself.  If that's `dir1/.gitignore`, this ignores `dir1/file2`, but not `dir1/dir2/file2`.

There are two more things you need to be aware of here:

- "Ignore" doesn't mean what a lot of people think it means.
- If you let Git ignore a directory, Git never gets around to looking *inside* the directory.  This makes it impossible to "un-ignore" stuff inside the directory.

Both of these trip people up, so be aware of them.  They have nothing to do with the syntax of the entries themselves, though, so I won't cover them here.